# Convergence of sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+(-1)^n)^p} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've the following sum: 
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+(-1)^n)^p} $$

I think it converges for $p>0 $ but I can't find a good way to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
Try to rewrite the denominator, you should able to find that :
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(n+(-1)^n)^p}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^p}$$
Then apply the [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) to conclude that the sum exist iff $p>0$

Comment: Unless I'm wrong the right sum runs from 1 to infinity. 

If it is the case then I found the answer. Big thanks.

Comment: @danny11, I don't think so. Try to write the first term and you'll see ;)

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: @danny11, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

In the same spirit as Fabian, separate odd and even values of $n$ and look how is structured the sequence. You should arrive to Fabian's result.